# Does anyone know how to remove the "black lines" from this graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am using the R programming language and following this tutorial over here: https://michael.hahsler.net/SMU/EMIS7332/R/viz_classifier.html .

I simulated some data and plotted the results as per the tutorial:

```
library(cluster)
library(Rtsne)
library(dplyr)

library(randomForest)
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)


#PART 1 : Create Data

#generate 4 random variables : response_variable ~ var_1 , var_2, var_3

var_1 <- rnorm(10000,1,4)
var_2<-rnorm(10000,10,5)
var_3 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05) )
response_variable <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.6) )


#put them into a data frame called "f"
f <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, response_variable)

#declare var_3 and response_variable as factors
f$response_variable = as.factor(f$response_variable)
f$var_3 = as.factor(f$var_3)

#create id
f$ID <- seq_along(f[,1])

#PART 2: random forest

#split data into train set and test set
index = createDataPartition(f$response_variable, p=0.7, list = FALSE)
train = f[index,]
test = f[-index,]

#create random forest statistical model
rf = randomForest(response_variable ~ var_1 + var_2 + var_3, data=train, ntree=20, mtry=2)

#have the model predict the test set
pred = predict(rf, test, type = "prob")
labels = as.factor(ifelse(pred[,2]>0.5, "A", "B"))
confusionMatrix(labels, test$response_variable)

#PART 3: Visualize in 2D (source: https://dpmartin42.github.io/posts/r/cluster-mixed-types)

gower_dist <- daisy(test[, -c(4,5)],
                    metric = "gower")

gower_mat <- as.matrix(gower_dist)

labels = data.frame(labels)
labels$ID = test$ID


tsne_obj <- Rtsne(gower_dist,  is_distance = TRUE)

tsne_data <- tsne_obj$Y %>%
    data.frame() %>%
    setNames(c("X", "Y")) %>%
    mutate(cluster = factor(labels$labels),
           name = labels$ID)

plot = ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y), data = tsne_data) +
    geom_point(aes(color = labels$labels))

plotly_plot = ggplotly(plot)


a = tsne_obj$Y
a = data.frame(a)
data = a
data$class = labels$labels


decisionplot <- function(model, data, class = NULL, predict_type = "class",
                         resolution = 100, showgrid = TRUE, ...) {
    
    if(!is.null(class)) cl <- data[,class] else cl <- 1
    data <- data[,1:2]
    k <- length(unique(cl))
    
    plot(data, col = as.integer(cl)+1L, pch = as.integer(cl)+1L, ...)
    
    # make grid
    r <- sapply(data, range, na.rm = TRUE)
    xs <- seq(r[1,1], r[2,1], length.out = resolution)
    ys <- seq(r[1,2], r[2,2], length.out = resolution)
    g <- cbind(rep(xs, each=resolution), rep(ys, time = resolution))
    colnames(g) <- colnames(r)
    g <- as.data.frame(g)
    
    ### guess how to get class labels from predict
    ### (unfortunately not very consistent between models)
    p <- predict(model, g, type = predict_type)
    if(is.list(p)) p <- p$class
    p <- as.factor(p)
    
    if(showgrid) points(g, col = as.integer(p)+1L, pch = ".")
    
    z <- matrix(as.integer(p), nrow = resolution, byrow = TRUE)
    contour(xs, ys, z, add = TRUE, drawlabels = FALSE,
            lwd = 2, levels = (1:(k-1))+.5)
    
    invisible(z)
}


model <- randomForest(class ~ ., data=data, mtry=2, ntrees=500)
 final_plot = decisionplot(model, data, class = "class", main = "rf (1)")
```

Now, I am trying to remove the "black lines" from this plot. Briefly, when the image buffers, there are no black lines. But then the black lines later appear. Does anyone know how to remove these lines?

The closest I got was here:

```
plot(data[,c(1:2)], col = data[,3])
```

But I am trying to keep the format of the plot the same (as it was when the black lines were present).

Thanks

Comment: Just remove the `contours` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as provided in the comments: (remove contour statement)

```
library(cluster)
library(Rtsne)
library(dplyr)

library(randomForest)
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)


#PART 1 : Create Data

#generate 4 random variables : response_variable ~ var_1 , var_2, var_3

var_1 <- rnorm(10000,1,4)
var_2<-rnorm(10000,10,5)
var_3 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05) )
response_variable <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.6) )


#put them into a data frame called "f"
f <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, response_variable)

#declare var_3 and response_variable as factors
f$response_variable = as.factor(f$response_variable)
f$var_3 = as.factor(f$var_3)

#create id
f$ID <- seq_along(f[,1])

#PART 2: random forest

#split data into train set and test set
index = createDataPartition(f$response_variable, p=0.7, list = FALSE)
train = f[index,]
test = f[-index,]

#create random forest statistical model
rf = randomForest(response_variable ~ var_1 + var_2 + var_3, data=train, ntree=20, mtry=2)

#have the model predict the test set
pred = predict(rf, test, type = "prob")
labels = as.factor(ifelse(pred[,2]>0.5, "A", "B"))
confusionMatrix(labels, test$response_variable)

#PART 3: Visualize in 2D (source: https://dpmartin42.github.io/posts/r/cluster-mixed-types)

gower_dist <- daisy(test[, -c(4,5)],
                    metric = "gower")

gower_mat <- as.matrix(gower_dist)

labels = data.frame(labels)
labels$ID = test$ID


tsne_obj <- Rtsne(gower_dist,  is_distance = TRUE)

tsne_data <- tsne_obj$Y %>%
    data.frame() %>%
    setNames(c("X", "Y")) %>%
    mutate(cluster = factor(labels$labels),
           name = labels$ID)

plot = ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y), data = tsne_data) +
    geom_point(aes(color = labels$labels))

plotly_plot = ggplotly(plot)


a = tsne_obj$Y
a = data.frame(a)
data = a
data$class = labels$labels


decisionplot <- function(model, data, class = NULL, predict_type = "class",
                         resolution = 100, showgrid = TRUE, ...) {
    
    if(!is.null(class)) cl <- data[,class] else cl <- 1
    data <- data[,1:2]
    k <- length(unique(cl))
    
    plot(data, col = as.integer(cl)+1L, pch = as.integer(cl)+1L, ...)
    
    # make grid
    r <- sapply(data, range, na.rm = TRUE)
    xs <- seq(r[1,1], r[2,1], length.out = resolution)
    ys <- seq(r[1,2], r[2,2], length.out = resolution)
    g <- cbind(rep(xs, each=resolution), rep(ys, time = resolution))
    colnames(g) <- colnames(r)
    g <- as.data.frame(g)
    
    ### guess how to get class labels from predict
    ### (unfortunately not very consistent between models)
    p <- predict(model, g, type = predict_type)
    if(is.list(p)) p <- p$class
    p <- as.factor(p)
    
    if(showgrid) points(g, col = as.integer(p)+1L, pch = ".")
    
    z <- matrix(as.integer(p), nrow = resolution, byrow = TRUE)
    
    
    invisible(z)
}


model <- randomForest(class ~ ., data=data, mtry=2, ntrees=500)
 aaaa = decisionplot(model, data, class = "class", main = "rf (1)")
```